# Installing a particular file in the GAC?

Tags: dll, crystal-reports, assemblies, gac

when I wanna to run a click once deployed vb.net win-application on my machine it says:

"Unable to install or run the application. The application requires that assembly CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine Version 10.2.3600.0 be installed in the Global Assembly Cache(GAC) first."

I have installed crystal Reports 8.5 before and recently Crystal reports 10

So, what's wrong?

Comment: Wrong version in the gac? Missing publisher policy?

Answer (score 2):

Check your GAC for the presence of this file, and check the version of the file (if it is present).

[GAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Assembly_Cache) can be found by....

> The newer interface, the Assembly
>   Cache Viewer, is integrated into
>   Windows Explorer. Simply browsing
>   %windir%\assembly\ (for example,
>   C:\WINDOWS\assembly)

If you need to add this, [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex0ss12c%28VS.80%29.aspx) is good guide

Hope this helps.